# Is IPTABLES obsolete when behind a router?

Tags: centos, iptables

I'm still quite noobish when it comes to networking. I was fiddling around with squid on centos and i was wondering whether turning on iptables when your centos box is behind your isp modem/router has any use at all? Since there's already a firewall in the isp-machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely no. `iptables` mission is not just port blocking, but also forwarding, changing default routing rules, it even allows TCP packet mangling and so many other complex tasks.

Having an additional firewall before your machine doesn't make `iptables` useless neither. As far as security concerns go, one should always design systems with several security layers (when possible) rather than just one, since a device can fail, have security bugs, be hacked...

This way you make sure that you have another security layer behind the first device, for any issue that might happen.